# What is a $c_1$-map for Riemann-Roch theorems?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory, complex-manifolds

[Atiyah and Hirzebruch](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1959-65-04/S0002-9904-1959-10344-X/home.html) define a $c_1$-map to spell out Riemann-Roch theorem for (compact and connected) smooth manifolds. The definition is following: a map $f:Y \to X$ is called a $c_1$-map if we are given an element $c_1\in H^2(Y,\mathbb Z)$ such that

$$c_1 \equiv w_2(Y)-f^*w_2(X)\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 2). \tag{$\ast$}$$

I am confused by this definition, because the existence of $c_1$ is contained in the definition. If we distinguish $c_1$ in "$c_1$-map" and $c_1$ in the definition, then the definition says almost nothing, because the universal coefficient theorem ($H^2(Y,\mathbb Z)\otimes\mathbb Z_2 \cong H^2(Y,\mathbb Z_2)$) allows us to find an integral cohomology class $c_1$ satisfying ($*$) for each $f$. Therefore the definition seems to fail to define a class of maps (or seems to say only the choice of $c_1$).

**Questions:**

1. What exactly do Atiyah and Hirzebruch want to define? A class of maps or a choice of $c_1$? Or do I fail to understand the definition?
2. The integral cohomology class $c_1$ is contained in the Riemann-Roch theorem
   $$f_!(y)\cdot \hat{\mathfrak{A}}(X) = f_*(y \cdot e^{c_1/2} \cdot \hat{\mathfrak{A}}(Y)).$$
   Why does not the choice of $c_1$ affect the identity?
3. According to Remark following the theorem in the paper, if $X$ and $Y$ are complex manifolds and $f$ is holomorphic, then we can delete $e^{c_1/2}$ from the formula. Why can we delete it?

Comment: Another way to phrase it is this: suppose you are given the map $f$. Then for an element $c_1$ in $H^2$, we say that $f$ is a $c_1$-map if the displayed identity holds. So for some choices of cohomology class $c_1$, $f$ will be a $c_1$-map; for others, it won't. In particular, every map is a $c_1$-map for _some_ choice of $c_1$. The phrase "$f$ is a $c_1$-map" describes a property of the pair $(f,c_1)$, not just of the map.

Comment: By the way, I agree that the original phrasing is very unclear.

Comment: Thanks. So the word "$c_1$-map $f$" means the choice of the integral cohomology class $c_1$.